# What happens when I change the channel on my wireless router?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-networking

If I change the channel on my wireless router, while my multiple devices are connected, how will they be affected, if at all? Is it like changing a TV channel, such that you see the change, but, otherwise, you can keep going without missing a beat? Or is it a totally "invisible" change to the devices, such that, in essence, changing the channel won't affect the other devices? Will they see a temporary "glitch" or will they have to reboot/restart? (assume all devices are fully-compliant with modern standards and updates)

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User.

Answer (score 1):

If the wireless access point within your router changes radio channels, all clients are disconnected. They'll start scanning, rediscovering the SSID and likely rejoin the Wi-Fi network quickly - but not without "missing a beat".